# Switching Cameras that a User is looking through

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game that has 2 cameras. one to spectate the main game and one to roam.
But when I disable the camera spectating the main game and try to enable it again via script it doesn't want to work. Here is my script so far (Everything is fetched with GameObject.Find due to me making this an online game and instantiating everything when players load into the game)

This script is located in the player

```
    void Update()
    {
        if(photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if(!hasRan)
            {
                if(GameManager.isSpectating)
                {
                    textPanel = GameObject.Find("TextPanel");
                    text = GameObject.Find("TextPanelText").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
                    textPanel.SetActive(true);
                    text.text = "Press F to stop Spectating";
                    hasRan = true;
                    isSpectating = true;
                }
            }
            if (!hasPressed && !isSpectating && GameManager.isSpectating)
            {
                textPanel.SetActive(true);
                text.text = "Press F to Spectate";
                isSpectating = false;
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {
                    isSpectating = true;
                    hasPressed = true;
                    activeCams = false;
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                    GameObject.Find("DartCam").GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
                    GameObject.Find("DartCam").GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
                    GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = false;
                    GetComponentInChildren<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                    text.text = "Press F to stop Spectating";
                }
            }
            if (!isSpectating && activeCams)
            {
                GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = true;
                GetComponentInChildren<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
                Look();
                Move();
            }
            if(isSpectating)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {
                    isSpectating = false;
                    activeCams = true;
                    hasPressed = false;
                    GameObject.Find("DartCam").GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
                    GameObject.Find("DartCam").GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
                    GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = true;
                    GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>().enabled = true;
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when bool isSpectating is false and you press key F the bool isSpectating is set to true and spectating camera is enable and after that in next condition if(isSpectating) you disable that camera. that's why it won't work.

Comment: I see what you mean by this. But how would I avoid disabling it as it is checking if I pressed F on the same frame which I am. As isSpectating is enabled it will disable it as I pressed F in that same scene. Should I use a bool to check if it done in the same frame and at the end of the frame set the bool to false?

Comment: Just return from the first condition